# Mapping in SQL - two possibilities

Tags: sql, mapping

I have a SQL table Values:

```
id (int) | group (int) | value (int)
```

and I want to map a `value` to string. For one `group`, one `value` can only be mapped to one string. From two different groups, one value can be mapped to two different strings.

Is it better to create table like this

```
map_id (int) | group (int) | value (int) | mapped (string)
```

or like this

```
map_id (int) | group (int) | mapping (text)
```

where mapping is a text field e.g.

```
5=something
6=another string
7=next string
```

and finally map in program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is generally better.  The latter violates the 1st normal form (1NF).  Denormalization is a valid real-life approach, but maybe not for this case.